# Mean of a possible MLE ,cant figure out the distribution of the sum of $x^{2}$

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, statistical-inference

I would like to know:

1. Is $\beta$ a MLE?
2. If yes what is the mean of it: $E(\beta)=$?

given:

$x$ is a random variable

$$f(x)=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi \theta^2}}\exp \left(-\frac{x^2}{2\theta^2}\right)$$ with  $\theta,x>0$

I got $\beta = \sqrt{\sum x_i^2/n}$

Doing the likelihood function and the first derivative however when I check the 2nd derivative it was not evident to be negative.

If anyone could help I would appreciate a lot!

Comment: I cant prove it,it supposed to be but now I am not so sure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will not get into much detail. As pointed out the first order condition
leads to the estimator
$$ \hat{\theta} = \sqrt{\frac{\sum_{i = 1}^n x_i^2}{n}} $$
The second order condition leads to
$$ \frac{n}{\theta^2} - \frac{3}{\theta^4} \sum_{i = 1}^n x_i^2 $$
Upon substituion of $\hat{\theta}$, this becomes
$$ - \frac{2 n^2}{\sum_{i = 1}^n x_i^2} < 0 $$
which is what needed to be verified.

Comment: Ok it is a MLE but how can I know the Mean of it ??

Comment: Do you know about Jensen's inequality?

Comment: Yes, I will try it thanks :)

Comment: but the equality is only for linear functions so I would only get some kind of bound,how should I use it ?

Comment: You could use it to quickly prove that the estimator is biased (here different from $\theta/\sqrt{n}$). Its square is unbiased though.

Comment: But I can´t know the mean of the estimator it is a tricky question I dont even need it to know it, in the first place ,thank YOU  a lot !!!!!

Comment: However I need the second moment ?

Comment: $E[X^2]=\theta^2$. It is easy to verify by computing the integral. And $E[X]=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}} \theta$

Comment: I need to do on paper but I almost finish with this exercise thank you @learner again !!!

Answer (score 0):

It's the MLE for $\theta$. We it a normal distribution it would be $\sigma$, by symmetry it is the same for your truncated normal.  The truncation affects the mean, but as $x^2 = (-x)^2$, not the estimate of $\theta$.

The bias isn't that simple, but is the same as for a normal: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unbiased_estimation_of_standard_deviation